# Web Development on different browsers

Tags: web-services, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, web

I am new to development of websites

I have query why does a website work on some browsers while not for others

I have designed a website which works on one browser IE and then it does not for other computers IE 
it does not goes through hit .

What precautions should I TAKE SO THAT MY WEBSITE WORKS ON EVERY BROWSER

The warning which I got was as below

The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

but I did not understood Kindly explain and give some tips

Ok I think I got something wrong with my code or internet speed

I kept the code in Developers option and let it wait then the hit went through all the 4 states and I got a response

Am I missing something ... In normal mode the hit does not go through all the states

Comment: Hard question. I think there's a tradeoff here. If you want to be compatible, you have to keep things simple, rely on solid and mature libs. But if you want something fancy, you can just choose more popular browsers and work with them. I am assuming you're a freelancer or work with limited resources / small team

Comment: Too broad, that said if you make your site work in chrome or firefox, you'll likely have much less to do. IE is in general the problem not the solution.

Comment: Think that today, every browser also means cellphones, tablets and my tv set ;-)

Comment: my website just worked on ie tht to only on one pc not in another  and did not went through the hit in chrome nor in firefox ... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your mode as synchronous to true